# Simple database design - some columns have multiple values

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

Caveat: very new to database design/modeling, so bear with me :)

I'm trying to design a simple database that stores information about images in an archive.  Along with `file_name` (which is one distinct string), I have fields like `genre` and `starring` where each field might contains multiple strings (if an image is associated with multiple genres, and/or if an image has multiple actors in it).

Right now the database is just a single table keyed on `file_name`, and the fields like `starring` and `genre` just have multiple comma-separated values stored.  I can query it fine by using wildcards and `like` and `in` operators, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to break out the data such that it is easier to use/query.  For instance, I'd like to be able to find how many unique actors are represented in the archive, but I don't think that's possible with the current model.

I realize this is a pretty elementary question about data modeling, but any guidance anyone can provide or reading you can direct me to would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create extra tables in order to stick with the normalization. In your situation you need 4 extra tables to represent these n->m relations(2 extra would be enough if the relations were 1->n).

Tables:

**image**(id, file_name)

**genre**(id, name)

**image_genres**(image_id, genre_id)

**stars**(id, name, ...)

**image_stars**(image_id, star_id)

And some data in tables:

#### image table

| id | file_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | /users/home/song/empire.png |
| 2 | /users/home/song/promiscuous.png |

#### genre table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pop |
| 2 | blues |
| 3 | rock |

#### image_genres table

| image_id | genre_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

#### stars table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jay-Z |
| 2 | Alicia Keys |
| 3 | Nelly Furtado |
| 4 | Timbaland |

#### image_stars table

| image_id | star_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

For unique actor count in database you can simply run the sql query below

```
SELECT COUNT(name) FROM stars
```